Geodesic submanifold of Grassmannian manifold
Consider the Grassmannian manifold $\text{Gr}(n, k)$, which is the space of $k$-dimensional subspaces of $\mathbb{R}^n$. A submanifold of the Grassmannian is said to be a geodesic submanifold if the geodesics within the submanifold are also geodesics in the ambient Grassmannian manifold.
Now, suppose we have a particular submanifold of the Grassmannian, which is defined by a rank-1 projection matrix of the form:
$$
P = \frac{v v^T}{\|v\|^2}, \quad v = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha \sqrt{2} \\ \beta / \alpha \\ 1 \end{pmatrix},
$$
where $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ and $v$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that parametrizes the submanifold.
I am trying to understand how the geodesic submanifold condition applies to this specific submanifold embedded in the Grassmannian $\text{Gr}(3, 1)$. Could someone explain the conditions under which this submanifold would be a geodesic submanifold and how to verify this mathematically?
Thank you for your help!

Could you state more precisely what the definition of the submanifold is? One possible way to do this calculation is to use the fact that a submanifold is geodesic if and only if its second fundamental form vanishes.

So you're talking about $\Bbb RP^2$. The standard metric comes from the standard metric on $S^2$ and the geodesics are totally well understood. I am confused about your actual question. Each $v$ defines a line in $\Bbb R^3$, and your two-parameter family gives you an open subset of $\Bbb RP^2$. Is this really the question you're asking, or am I confused?

@Deane Actually one possible way coming in my mind see we already know that we have the submanifold so if we can prove that the geodesic in the submanifold is also a geodesic in the manifold then it will be geodesic submanifold
